# MySQL SELECT * and Percentage

Tags: mysql

Bit of a newb with MySQL and not proficient enough to understand the logic of the statements I am trying to put together.

I have this query;

`SELECT FORMAT(SUM(won/total*100),2) AS PCT FROM table_name WHERE Status='Current'`

Which works fine to return the win% for the total sum of all records, but I am looking to return the result by row?

Essentially what I am trying to achieve is the win% for each **row** using 
`SELECT *`, but I can not use SELECT * in combination with working out the percentage.

Or I can and probably have the logic wrong, i'm not sure.

The returned result would be something like;

```
Manager | Win%

Arsene Wenger | 57.24%

Alex Ferguson | 48.02%
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Query:

```
SELECT Manager,FORMAT(SUM(won/total*100),2) AS PCT 
FROM table_name 
WHERE Status='Current'
GROUP BY Manager
```

If u want for Each **Row**

```
SELECT Manager,FORMAT((won/total*100),2) AS PCT 
FROM table_name 
WHERE Status='Current'
```

Comment: The each *row* statement is exactly what I needed, thanks you all for taking time to answer my 2 day old headache!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html) statement.
Or, if you wan't to return the %-age for *all* rows, you must remove [`SUM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) since that will aggregate all rows returned into on sum.

Answer (score 1):

you have to group rows by the name of the person, something like

`SELECT FORMAT(SUM(won/total*100),2) AS PCT FROM table_name WHERE Status='Current' group by manager ;`